# SwiftUI view API patterns

Tags: swift, design-patterns, swiftui

I am writing a SwiftUI framework package where I want to have some APIs that allow presentation of a view. For these views, I always want them presented above the presenting view as a modal sheet view (I want to disallow having these views embedded as a subview in an app's view).

Apple appears to have very few system APIs like this, but I have found this API - which behaves as I expect:

`public func fileImporter(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, allowedContentTypes: [UTType], onCompletion: @escaping (_ result: Result<URL, Error>) -> Void) -> some View`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/fileimporter(ispresented:allowedcontenttypes:allowsmultipleselection:oncompletion:)

Note that Apple has implemented this as a `View` extension, so you can simply use like so:

```
Button("Import..") {
    self.showingFileImporter = true
}
.fileImporter(isPresented: $showingFileImporter, allowedContentTypes: [.pdf]) { result in
    // got result
}
```

So, I'm trying to use this pattern to implement my own API, something like:

```
func mySomethingSelector(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, completion: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View
```

However, I'm unsure how to start the implementation. The first thing I noticed is that `fileImporter` actually returns `some View`, but this is not the screen that's actually presented. So, we need to return some kind of wrapper view, that then presents above the wrapper view? (Note that I assume that Apple has actually implemented `fileImporter` by bridging to UIKit - and possibly out of process. But I just want to use standard SwiftUI for my implementation).

Anyway, hopefully this makes sense. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple implementation might look like this, using a `sheet` to display your custom `View`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present") {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }
        .mySomethingSelector(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            print("Done")
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func mySomethingSelector(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, completion: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.sheet(isPresented: isPresented, onDismiss: completion) {
            Text("My View")
        }
    }
}
```